# Wraptable interferes with the next page

Tags: tables, wrap

I've got a wrapped table on the right, it reaches the end of the page and stops, and the text next to it finishes its paragraph in line with where the table finishes. The line on the next page stops off halfway through like the table is still going on.

Anyone know how to prevent this so that the line on the next page is full width?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 4):

wrapfig has an optional parameter that controls how many lines are short, so you can over-ride its default and specify just the number of lines before the break. The file says

> \LaTeX\ calculates the number of short lines needed based on the
>   height of the figure and the length "\intextsep".  You can override
>   this guess by giving the first optional argument (parameter "#1")
>   specifying the number of shortened lines (counting each displayed
>   equation as 3 lines).
>   This is particularly useful when the surrounding text contains extra
>   vertical spacing that is not accounted for automatically.